# How do I call a static image from the CSS of an element with Django?

Tags: css, django, jinja2

I used bootstrap studio to make a simple frontend page and I'm learning django so I'm using a bootstrap frontend for the app.

All the static resources are in a static folder that i call using:
`{% load static %}`

And the image is at: `static 'img/map.png'`

In the below code, the div is calling the background image using css - *background:url('assets/img/map.png')*
But of course this wont work because I have a folder called static with the static assets

```
<div class="col" style="text-align: center;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex-flow: column;min-width: 300px;background: url('assets/img/map.png');background-size: cover;">
        <div style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);margin-top: 66px;margin-bottom: 66px;">
            <h1>Diverse Locations</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way I can make the div point to the right background image?

Note: I created the static folder by copying the static content into the project folder, defined the STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS variables and ran the command: python manage.py collectstatic.

Comment: Override it with more specific CSS?

Comment: Try using the `static` template tag: `background: url('{% static 'img/map.png' %}');`

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks that worked. You can add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `static` template tag: `background: url('{% static 'img/map.png' %}');`

As suggested by @IainShelvington